# Can we get Xenserver VMs provisioned by MAAS?

Tags: maas, kvm-virtualization, virtualization

currently i am using KVM, and KVM vms can be managed by MAAS but i am wondering, is it possible that Xenserver VMs will also work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support managing VMs with MAAS - though I'm glad it's working for you - so the answer is that we don't support Xen VMs directly from MAAS either. MAAS really is intended only for managing physical machines.

However, you can use MAAS with [Juju](https://juju.ubuntu.com/) to deploy OpenStack; the [nova-compute](https://jujucharms.com/fullscreen/search/precise/nova-compute-13/) charm has support for Xen.

Comment: hi, sorry i asked question in wrong way, i didn't mean manage VMs, its just that pxe booting VMs(from xenserver) and then use them in juju to deploy services. I want to go for HA openstack deployment as per ubuntu guide which needs 32 servers, And as i dont have 32 physical severs, i was thinking to have few of them on virtual machines.